# What is the Scheme function to find an element in a list?

Tags: lisp, scheme

I have a list of elements '(a b c) and I want to find if (true or false) x is in it, where x can be 'a or 'd, for instance. Is there a built in function for this?

Comment: Use the language reference to find it:

http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS//HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.3.2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you need to compare using one of the build in equivalence operators, you can use [`memq`, `memv`, or `member`](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_428), depending on whether you want to look for equality using [`eq?`, `eqv?`, or `equal?`](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.1), respectively.

```
> (memq 'a '(a b c))
'(a b c)
> (memq 'b '(a b c))
'(b c)
> (memq 'x '(a b c))
#f
```

As you can see, these functions return the sublist starting at the first matching element if they find an element. This is because if you are searching a list that may contain booleans, you need to be able to distinguish the case of finding a `#f` from the case of not finding the element you are looking for. A list is a true value (the only false value in Scheme is `#f`) so you can use the result of `memq`, `memv`, or `member` in any context expecting a boolean, such as an `if`, `cond`, `and`, or `or` expression.

```
> (if (memq 'a '(a b c))
     "It's there! :)"
     "It's not... :(")
"It's there! :)"
```

What is the difference between the three different functions? It's based on which equivalence function they use for comparison. `eq?` (and thus `memq`) tests if two objects are the same underlying object; it is basically equivalent to a pointer comparison (or direct value comparison in the case of integers). Thus, two strings or lists that look the same may not be `eq?`, because they are stored in different locations in memory. `equal?` (and thus `member?`) performs a deep comparison on lists and strings, and so basically any two items that print the same will be `equal?`. `eqv?` is like `eq?` for almost anything but numbers; for numbers, two numbers that are numerically equivalent will always be `eqv?`, but they may not be `eq?` (this is because of bignums and rational numbers, which may be stored in ways such that they won't be `eq?`)

```
> (eq? 'a 'a)
#t
> (eq? 'a 'b)
#f
> (eq? (list 'a 'b 'c) (list 'a 'b 'c))
#f
> (equal? (list 'a 'b 'c) (list 'a 'b 'c))
#t
> (eqv? (+ 1/2 1/3) (+ 1/2 1/3))
#t
```

(Note that some behavior of the functions is undefined by the specification, and thus may differ from implementation to implementation; I have included examples that should work in any R<sup>5</sup>RS compatible Scheme that implements exact rational numbers)

If you need to search for an item in a list using an equivalence predicate different than one of the built in ones, then you may want [`find`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#find) or [`find-tail`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#find-tail) from SRFI-1:

```
> (find-tail? (lambda (x) (> x 3)) '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
'(4 5 6)
```

Comment: What is the function name `memq` short for?

Comment: `memq` is one of the `member` family of functions, finding an item in a list based on some kind of equivalence (like the others mentioned, `member` and `memv`). The `q`, `v`, or full name connect it to the three equivalence functions that they each use; `memq` uses `eq?` to test equivalence, `memv` uses `eqv?` to test equivalence, and `member` uses `equal?` to test equivalence. See the linked documentation on equivalence functions for the difference between them.

Comment: Thank you! So `memq` can be considered as `mem-q`, and `memv` as `mem-v`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
> (cond ((member 'a '(a b c)) '#t) (else '#f))
#t
> (cond ((member 'd '(a b c)) '#t) (else '#f))
#f
```

member returns everything starting from where the element is, or #f. A cond is used to convert this to true or false.

Comment: `#t` is fine also, instead of `'#t`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "find"

Basics - The simplest case is just (find Entry List), usually used as a predicate: "is Entry in List?". If it succeeds in finding the element in question, it returns the first matching element instead of just "t". **(Taken from second link.)**

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node145.html

-or-

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/Lisp-Notes/Higher-Order.html

Comment: The question was about Scheme, not Common Lisp.

Comment: Read the title: 'What is the SCHEME function to find an element in a list?'. Scheme is a dialect in the family of Lisp languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a built in function, but you can create one:

```
(define (occurrence x lst)
       (if (null? lst) 0    
            (if (equal? x (car lst))  (+ 1 (occurrence x (cdr lst)))
                                     (occurrence x (cdr lst)) 
            )
       )
)
```

Ỳou will get in return the number of occurrences of `x` in the list. you can extend it with `true` or `false` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (define (member? x list)
     (cond ((null? list) #f)
           ((equal? x (car list)) #t)
           (else   (member? x (cdr list)))))
```

The procedure return #t (true) or #f (false)

```
(member? 10 '(4 2 3))
```

output is #f