# Checking if element is present in list in racket

Tags: string, list, racket

How to check if an element is present in a list, both taken as input from the function call, without using the lambda? I was trying member? but could not get it.

```
(define (find-string (lst lst str ua)
    (cond ((member? ua lst) #t)
    (else #f))
```

Comment: It seems that you're trying to specify the type of each parameter in the procedure declaration? it doesn't work like that in Racket...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694669/what-is-the-scheme-function-to-find-an-element-in-a-list) may help.

Answer (score 4):

The use of member would work it's just that you are adding extra "?" in front of the function none is required

```
 (member 2 (list 1 2 3 4)) [1]
```

would return true

another way around is writing ones own recursive function

```
(define (is-in-list list value)
 (cond
  [(empty? list) false]
  [(= (first list) value) true]
  [else (is-in-list (rest list) value)]))
```

[1]https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._member%29%29

Comment: I am unsure if you are asking a question or not. Please **avoid sentences that require a questionmark at their end**.

Comment: ? was an operator not  for question updated by adding quote on it

Answer (score 3):

First, the way with `lambda` and `ormap` (for testing):

```racket
; ismember? :: String List-of-Strings -> Bool
(define (ismember1? str strs) (ormap [lambda (s) (string=? s str)] strs) )
```

Second way, with `for/or`, without `lambda`:

```racket
(define (ismember2? str strs) 
   (for/or ([s (in-list strs)])
      (string=? s str) ) )
```

Third way, with `member`, without `lambda`:

```racket
(define (ismember3? str strs) (if [member str strs] #t #f) )
```

Refer to the official Racket [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._member%29%29) for `member`.

Notice that the last version is actually the *worst* in terms of performance.

Comment: the OP's order of arguments is reversed though. so their intended function could be better named "contains".